# Get gridbag constraints of a panel

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I want to progamatically get the grid bag constraints of a panel which is already been placed. How do i do that??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GridBagLayout has the method

```
public GridBagConstraints getConstraints(Component comp)
```

Comment: (+1) And a link: http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html#getConstraints(java.awt.Component)

Comment: or this link: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html#getConstraints(java.awt.Component) for JDK 6